# Selenium InternetExplorerDriver - Windows 10 IE 11, Throws TimeOutException when certificate prompt appears

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, certificate, windows-10

I work on an automation team for browser and desktop automation, and we are currently running into an issue with InternetExplorerDriver and Windows 10.

We have tests that require IE to run. Once we get to the page, we are forced to choose a certificate, which we use SikuliX to do that. In Windows 7 this works fine. For whatever reason on Windows 10 it is able to spin up the IE browser and navigate to the page, but once the certificate prompt appears it hangs. Tried with both 32 and 64 bit drivers.

[Image of the browser and Certificate prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01paq.png)

Eventually it will throw a TimeoutException.

```
    Error Message: org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for page to load. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
    Command duration or timeout: 60.02 seconds
    Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1cd5757287168e54b817830adce9b0158d', time: '2016-06-30 19:26:09'
    System info: host: 'APE-Win10-Automation', ip: '10.40.88.120', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_71'
    Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
    Capabilities [{browserAttachTimeout=0, ie.enableFullPageScreenshot=true, enablePersistentHover=true, ie.forceCreateProcessApi=false, ie.forceShellWindowsApi=false, pageLoadStrategy=normal, ignoreZoomSetting=false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout=3000, version=11, platform=WINDOWS, nativeEvents=true, ie.ensureCleanSession=true, elementScrollBehavior=0, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches=, requireWindowFocus=false, browserName=internet explorer, initialBrowserUrl=http://localhost:31821/, javascriptEnabled=true, ignoreProtectedModeSettings=false, enableElementCacheCleanup=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
    Session ID: e461d42d-68ca-4103-81f8-f8c62d2a6091
    Stacktrace: 
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
    org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:316)
```

Manually if the cancel button is clicked on the certificate pop up before the TimeOutException is thrown, it will continue on. And here's the output from the IEDriver itself. It's the same for 64Bit driver and without the ignoring of protected modes.

```
I 2018-02-05 10:36:47:610 server.cc(86) Starting WebDriver server on port: '31375' on host: ''
I 2018-02-05 10:36:47:611 IEServer.cpp(33) Driver version: 3.3.0.0 (64-bit)
D 2018-02-05 10:36:47:611 server.cc(148) Civetweb ACL is -0.0.0.0/0,+127.0.0.1
D 2018-02-05 10:36:47:886 server.cc(281) Command: GET /status {}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:47:887 server.cc(355) Response: {"sessionId":"","status":0,"value":{"build":{"version":"3.3.0.0 (64-bit)"},"os":{"arch":"x64","name":"windows","version":"10.0.16299.15 (WinBuild.160101.0800)"}}}

D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:008 server.cc(281) Command: POST /session {"desiredCapabilities":{"ensureCleanSession":true,"ie.ensureCleanSession":true,"logLevel":"DEBUG","logFile":"IEOutput.txt","browserName":"internet explorer","ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true,"version":"","platform":"WINDOWS"}}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:009 IESession.cpp(53) Mutex acquired for session initalization
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:018 IESession.cpp(109) Releasing session initialization mutex
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:018 command.cc(36) Raw JSON command: { "name" : "newSession", "locator" : { }, "parameters" : {"desiredCapabilities":{"ensureCleanSession":true,"ie.ensureCleanSession":true,"logLevel":"DEBUG","logFile":"IEOutput.txt","browserName":"internet explorer","ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true,"version":"","platform":"WINDOWS"}} }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:019 BrowserFactory.cpp(146) Ignoring Protected Mode Settings: 1
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:019 BrowserFactory.cpp(152) Has Valid Protected Mode Settings: 0
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:033 BrowserFactory.cpp(133) Clearing cache with low mandatory integrity level as required on Windows Vista or later.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:034 BrowserFactory.cpp(850) Launching inetcpl.cpl via rundll32.exe to clear cache
D 2018-02-05 10:36:48:049 BrowserFactory.cpp(890) Waiting for rundll32.exe process to exit.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:50:696 BrowserFactory.cpp(895) Cache clearing complete.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:50:696 BrowserFactory.cpp(136) Clearing cache with normal process execution.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:50:696 BrowserFactory.cpp(850) Launching inetcpl.cpl via rundll32.exe to clear cache
D 2018-02-05 10:36:50:705 BrowserFactory.cpp(890) Waiting for rundll32.exe process to exit.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:56:323 BrowserFactory.cpp(895) Cache clearing complete.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:56:323 BrowserFactory.cpp(248) Starting IE using the IELaunchURL API
D 2018-02-05 10:36:56:862 BrowserFactory.cpp(202) IE launched successfully with process ID 8136
D 2018-02-05 10:36:56:862 BrowserFactory.cpp(208) Process with ID 8136 is executing iexplore.exe
D 2018-02-05 10:36:56:862 BrowserFactory.cpp(375) Using Active Accessibility to find IWebBrowser2 interface
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:379 BrowserFactory.cpp(434) Found window handle 0000000000550356 for window with class 'Internet Explorer_Server' belonging to process with id 8136
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:385 server.cc(281) Command: GET /favicon.ico {}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:385 server.cc(355) Response: { "status" : 404, "sessionId" : "<no session>", "value" : "Command not found: GET /favicon.ico" }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:460 BrowserFactory.cpp(396) Ignoring zoom setting: 0
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:533 BrowserFactory.cpp(694) Browser zoom level is 100%
I 2018-02-05 10:36:57:534 IECommandExecutor.cpp(650) Persistent hovering set to: 1
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:534 ProxyManager.cpp(111) Using existing system proxy settings.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:539 server.cc(355) Response: {"sessionId":"ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4","status":0,"value":{"browserAttachTimeout":0,"browserName":"internet explorer","elementScrollBehavior":0,"enableElementCacheCleanup":true,"enablePersistentHover":true,"ie.browserCommandLineSwitches":"","ie.enableFullPageScreenshot":true,"ie.ensureCleanSession":true,"ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout":3000,"ie.forceCreateProcessApi":false,"ie.forceShellWindowsApi":false,"ignoreProtectedModeSettings":true,"ignoreZoomSetting":false,"initialBrowserUrl":"http://localhost:31375/","javascriptEnabled":true,"nativeEvents":true,"pageLoadStrategy":"normal","platform":"WINDOWS","requireWindowFocus":false,"unexpectedAlertBehaviour":"dismiss","version":"11"}}

D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:558 server.cc(281) Command: POST /session/ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4/timeouts {"type":"page load","ms":60000}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:558 command.cc(36) Raw JSON command: { "name" : "timeouts", "locator" : { "sessionid" : "ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4" }, "parameters" : {"type":"page load","ms":60000} }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:558 IECommandExecutor.cpp(544) No alert handle is found
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:569 server.cc(355) Response: {"sessionId":"ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4","status":0,"value":null}

D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:581 server.cc(281) Command: POST /session/ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4/timeouts {"type":"script","ms":60000}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:581 command.cc(36) Raw JSON command: { "name" : "timeouts", "locator" : { "sessionid" : "ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4" }, "parameters" : {"type":"script","ms":60000} }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:581 IECommandExecutor.cpp(544) No alert handle is found
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:592 server.cc(355) Response: {"sessionId":"ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4","status":0,"value":null}

D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:597 server.cc(281) Command: DELETE /session/ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4/cookie {}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:597 command.cc(36) Raw JSON command: { "name" : "deleteAllCookies", "locator" : { "sessionid" : "ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4" }, "parameters" : {} }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:597 IECommandExecutor.cpp(544) No alert handle is found
I 2018-02-05 10:36:57:597 Browser.cpp(130) No child frame focus. Focus is on top-level frame
W 2018-02-05 10:36:57:652 HookProcessor.cpp(131) Unable to set Windows hook procedure. Driver is a 64-bit process, but browser is a 32-bit process.
W 2018-02-05 10:36:57:652 CookieManager.cpp(102) Cannot get cookies because driver and browser are not the same bit-ness.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:657 server.cc(355) Response: {"sessionId":"ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4","status":0,"value":null}

D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:691 server.cc(281) Command: POST /session/ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4/url {"url":"https://appstst1.site.com/internal/#app=284e&2439-selectedIndex=0"}
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:691 command.cc(36) Raw JSON command: { "name" : "get", "locator" : { "sessionid" : "ee57eecf-2a5c-4cfc-bfac-9b2fd614cdb4" }, "parameters" : {"url":"https://appstst1.site.com/internal/#app=284e&2439-selectedIndex=0"} }
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:692 IECommandExecutor.cpp(544) No alert handle is found
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:693 Browser.cpp(448) Navigate Events Completed.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:694 Browser.cpp(484) Browser ReadyState is not at least '4'; it was 1
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:895 Browser.cpp(448) Navigate Events Completed.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:57:895 Browser.cpp(464) Browser busy property is true.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:58:096 Browser.cpp(448) Navigate Events Completed.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:58:097 Browser.cpp(464) Browser busy property is true.
D 2018-02-05 10:36:58:298 Browser.cpp(448) Navigate Events Completed.
```

The last 2 lines in the above output repeat for a minute before it attempts to kill the driver.

Below are the capabilities we set

```
DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();
//Tried without and without this capability, still same result.
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS, true);
capabilities.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.IE_ENSURE_CLEAN_SESSION, true);
return new InternetExplorerDriver(capabilities);
```

Other than that here are the versions we are using

- OS - Windows 10 1709 (OS Build 16299.192)
- IE - 11.192.16299
- SeleniumRemoteDriver - 2.53.1(This is due to a Java 7 requirement, but it 
  has been
  tested with 3.3.0 up to 3.8.0; still same result)
- IEDriver - 3.3.0(Driver currently used. Have tried as low as 2.53.1 and up to 3.5.0; all same result)

We have been fighting with this for a while and don't understand why it's not working. Protected modes are set across all zones and iexplore.exe registry key has been added for both 32 and 64 bit. If

It works fine when there isn't any certificate to select, but we can't force auto select of certificates due to testing multiple environments and users who use our automation framework locally.

We are looking to see if anybody has seen this issue before and has a fix for it. If not would love some ideas, because we are out of them.

Comment: Why not check for the window that prompts about the certificate and automate clicking the cancel button?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it is the popup blocking the page from finished the loading, try during the test closing the popup..

Comment: @RyanWilson It is not possible to do that using Selenium.

Comment: Can you give a screen shot of the popup? I would like to see if it is coming from the website or from the browser object.

Comment: @RyanWilson Here's the link, [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01paq.png) which is also at the top of the post. And as for checking for the prompt, I don't believe Selenium has control over the certificate prompt, that's why we use SikuliX(image-based Automation API) for interacting with it. Which would usually run after navigating to the URL.But on Windows 10 it never completes the .get call.

Comment: @JayMar Selenium still has control at that point. I guess I could spin up a separate thread before we navigate to the URL that looks for the certificate prompt, but I don't know if that should be needed. Selenium finishes the .get call just fine on Windows 7

Comment: I've managed to get around things like this in the past. I had a library of functions I wrote that handle Windows windows, pardon the expression, which I wrote in C#. It could detect running processes and ui windows that were children of the desktop, which it could then drill down into and grab elements of those windows and cause click events and such. I still have a copy of this library which I could send you if you think that would be of any use. How I solved the issue was to spawn a new thread to handle clicking the button in the site which caused the popup and then let the main thread

Comment: handles finding the desktop's child window, in your case the security prompt and then drill down to the cancel button and invoke a click action on it.

Comment: Thank you. I'll take you up on using your libraries. I don't think we will try them right away though, since I am hoping this can be resolved without having to do any multi-threading.